# How to Update Entity with one to many relationship in flask-sqlachemy

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two models, class Parents and class Child, I want to update the attributes of these classses, suppose, we have:
 parent_name = "P1", child_name = {"c1", "c2", "c3"},
  After updating, we will have, parent_name = "P2", child_name = {"c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"

I already researched it, did not find the solution, give a suggestion

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child" backref='parent', passive_deletes=True)
    parent_name = db.Column(db.String(64))

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
   child_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
```

Comment: It would seem that you want to both change the `parent_name` attribute of an instance (cf. class) and add some children to it, but could you please reword the question to better describe what you really want.

Comment: exactly, i need to change some attributes of Parent, and also Child.

Comment: exactly, i need to change the parent_name attribute, and also child_name attribute.   my form , child_name attributes is dynamic fields (html),  so when update parent_name, probably i can add new field (child_name)

Answer (score 2):

```
parent = session.query(Parent).filter(Parent.name='P1').one()
parent.parent_name = 'P2'
parent.children.extend([Child(child_name='c4'), Child(childe_name='c5')])
session.commit()
```

First you query the parent from the session. Then you edit it, where it will remain in the session, so that when you commit, the changes in the session get propagated to the database.

Comment: i appreciate, your answer, but could not resolve , when i execute my code, there some error. -% self._rollback_exception-